# mongoengine with flask 'mongoengine.errors.NotRegistered' issue

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I want to use mongoengine with flask define two documents, user contains following topics and topic contains publish user.

I define `User` document in `user.py` and `Topic` document in `topic.py`. Only in `topic.py` I import `User` clakk, in `user.py` I don't import `Topic` class in order to avoid import loop.

```
user.py:
class User(Document):
    username = StringField(unique=True, required=True)
    following_topics = ListField(ReferenceField('Topic', reverse_delete_rule=PULL, unique=True))


topic.py:
from user import User
class Topic(Document, ModelMixin):
    title = StringField(default='')
    user = ReferenceField(User, required=True)
```

But when I start flask, there exits a error, how do i fix?

```
mongoengine.errors.NotRegistered: `Topic` has not been registered in the document registry. Importing the document class automatically registers it, has it been imported?
```

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Answer (score -1):

El problema se solucionaba importando en orden.

```
user.py: 
from topic import Topic 
class User(Document):
    username = StringField(unique=True, required=True)
    following_topics = ListField(ReferenceField('Topic', reverse_delete_rule=PULL, unique=True))

topic.py: 
class Topic(Document, ModelMixin):
    title = StringField(default='')
    user = ReferenceField('User', required=True)
```

Comment: Welcome! Please note that the [policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/) is that [questions and answers need to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange).